# How to remove number from the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, wordpress, redirection

I have wordoress site where I am getting /1 in the URL. I have checked siteurl,homeurl,permalinks but not sure why /1 is getting added in the URL

e.g `https://example.com/consulting/strategic-marketing/1/wp-content/themes/cubemanagement/favicon.ico`

The correct URL should be `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/cubemanagement/favicon.ico`

How can I setup redirection? I have tried below methods without success

1. `RewriteRule ^(.+?)-\d+/?$ /$1 [L,R=302]`
2. `RewriteRule ^$/$/1/$ https://www. example.com/ [L,R=301]`
3. `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/1/$ https://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: In your example there is more than just an additional `/1` in the URL? Does this apply to _all_ URLs? Where are you putting these rules in your `.htaccess` file? However, implementing a redirect as you suggest is not really an acceptable solution (even if this does "work") - it will be detrimental to SEO, your site users (slow) and your server (extra load).

Comment: Most probably the redirection happens in WordPress. If so you need to fix it there.

Comment: MR white, yes this happens with all URL If I removed all rules from .htaccess redirection still happens.

Comment: I have not set any rule or any redirection. Everything is correct but still I am not sure how /1 is getting added in he URL automatically. If you see cubemanagement.com/sitemap_index.xml, there as well you will get ;/1 added in the URL.

Comment: So, WordPress (or some plugin) is generating URLs with this additional `/1` (or `/consulting/strategic-marketing/1`?), including in your sitemap. You cannot "fix" this with a redirect, except to "correct" SEO if these incorrect URLs have been indexed or linked to by third parties, once the underlying URLs have been corrected. But do these "incorrect" URLs return a valid response or do they return a 404? As suggested above, you need to fix this in WordPress. (I have vague recollection that I have seen a similar question before, although I can't seem to find it??)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is WordPress related and would perhaps be better resolved on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/